# Drupal views - Use first argument to calculate second contextual filter argument

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-contextual-filters

I have one contextual filter argument passed to views (Node ID).

I would like to add Global Null contextual filter (or some other contextual filter) to calculate Node Updated datetime on-the-fly using "Provide default value / PHP Code" and NID passed as first argument.

Is it possible? Is the first argument available to second one as variable which can be used for PHP calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use PHP code to calculate second value - you could access the first argument with the `arg()` function, for example, if your url would look like this: `myview/arg1/arg2` - you could get arg1 value by calling `arg(1)`.

Actually it seems that you could simply use `$_GET` array to retrieve that value and use it as you like.
EDIT: But only if you aren't using clean URLs (which is unlikely)